# Trying to create method that sorts a sentence in ascending order by lower case first letter then descending by upper case first letter

Tags: c#, list

I'm trying to write a C# method that takes in the sentence, "The quick brown Fox jumped over the lazy Dog" and sorts it by first letter in ascending order then sorts any capitalized word in descending order at the end.  The result should look like this.... "brown jumped lazy over quick the The Fox Dog".

I'm stuck on how to add the three capitalized words to the empty list.  My code so far identifies the words that are capitalized but cannot figure out how to move those words to the empty list.  I have tried several methods including .Add().  I may be getting the syntax wrong.

My logic is that I would create a second list containing the capitalized words, sort both lists then concatenate them.  This is my first post here so my apologies in advance if things are not as clear as they should be.  Any help on this would be great.  Thanks

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string words = "The quick brown Fox jumped over the lazy Dog.";
            List<string> wordList = words.Split(' ').ToList();
            List<string> upperList = new List<string>();

            foreach (string word in wordList)
            {
                if (Char.IsUpper(word, 0))
                {
                    
                    Console.WriteLine(word);
                }
            }


            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your example does not match your description. In the example, both are sorted ascending but you said uppercase words should be sorted descending...

Comment: Yeah.  Saw that after I posted.  Order of words has been edited.  Thanks for catching that

Comment: Please edit your question to 1. make it more readable, it doesn't hurt to use paragraphs and 2. your example should match your description --> [edit]

Comment: Elaborate please.  Not sure how my example doesn't match my description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use LINQ:

```
List<string> wordList = words.Split(' ').
    OrderBy(word => char.IsUpper(word[0])).
    ThenBy(word => word).ToList();
```

Online demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/f59eUt